How can I record the sound when screen recording a Telegram videocall?
I use the built-in screen recording feature on my iPhone 12 mini. It works fine for YouTube. But it fails to capture the sound on Telegram: neither my voice nor the the voice of the people I videocall are recorded.
How can I record the sound when screen recording a Telegram videocall?
Here is how the screen recording looks like before I click on "start recording":


Reddit user Gold-Supermarket-342 answered:

You can’t record any calls on iOS for privacy reasons.

This restriction may be lifted with iOS 18:

However, at the company's annual Worldwide Developer Conference (WWDC) in June, Apple announced that iOS 18 will bring call recording and transcription to the iPhone this fall, as part of the new Apple Intelligence.

